# How to set Spinner position by item name, not by position?

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

I have `Spinner` that get it's values from `string-array` in array.xml file. It look like this:

```
<string-array name="arr_typl">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>12</item>
    <item>13</item>
</string-array>
```

When i want to get value from it I can get it with `getSelectedItem()`. But when I want to set `Spinner` with e.g number 13 I get an error like this:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=13
```

How can I do this that the `Spinner` will get value instead of position?
Here's my code:

```
spinner3_6 = Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).findViewById(R.id.sp3_6);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), R.array.arr_typl_3, R.layout.value_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner3_6.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can find position of your data in the array and pass it to Spinner:

```
final String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arr_typl);
final int position = Arrays.asList(values).indexOf("13");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a method in the Spinner like spinner.setSelectedItem(item), there isn't any.

You have to find the position of the item. You have the item, and you have the array of the spinner.

```
// The array that you are filling the spinner with
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);
// We have to find the position, initial position is -1, that means that we haven't found the position yet
int position = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].contains(item)) {
        position = i;
    }
}
```

After this, you can call `spinner.setSelection(position)`

Answer (score 0):

You should get String array like this

```
String[] stringArray =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shoes);
final int position = ArrayUtils.indexOf(stringArray ,"13");
```

then set the spinner as

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), stringArray , 
R.layout.value_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setSelection(position);
```